# C# IBM.Data.DB2.dll wrong version

Tags: c#, reference, db2, .net-assembly

I used IBM.Data.DB2 version=9.7.4.4 and everything worked perfectly. 
But I couldn't use a performance profiler and the support told me I should try 
with new IBM version = 10.1. I installed it and had problems at first. I had to register a reference to it in GAC, etc.

Now to my question: If I browse to C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\netf40_32\IBM.Data.DB2.dll 
and look properties I have version: 10.1.0.4 but when I add reference in visual studio 
I have version = 9.7.4.4 in the property window and I am not sure if the right version is used.

How do I get
the right version into property window in visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the IBM.Data.DB2.dll from C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\netf40_32\specific\IBM.Data.DB2.10.1.0.dll.

So I got the right version, then I had SQL1159 initialization error with db2 .net data provider reason code 2. The db2app.dll was searched in wrong directory (File not found: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01159n.html)

I reinstalled the db2 client and now it works...